# after Android uncaughtException, ActivityManager does force stop on new process

Tags: android, android-activity, uncaught-exception

I'm using Thread.setDefaultExceptionHandler() to try to start a new activity, effectively restarting the app. However, it appears that the ActivityManager is killing the new app process just after it gets started.

I've tried a number of experiements. The most successful was this code, in the exception handler:

```
public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent (getBaseContext (), RestartActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  PendingIntent pending =
    PendingIntent.getActivity (getBaseContext (), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

  try {
    pending.send ();
  }
  catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e1) {
    logE ("send pending intent:" + e1); // logE is a wrapper for Log.e().
  }

  System.exit (1);
}
```

In this case, the RestartActivity starts and displays, but only for a second. Then the app is completely gone and Android displays whatever was the prior app.

The log file contains this (note the pids are slightly different):

```
05-29 22:46:28.429 1465-3665/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.perinote.crashtest appid=10170 user=0: from pid 14484
05-29 22:46:28.429 1465-3665/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 14486:com.perinote.crashtest/u0a170 (adj 0): stop com.perinote.crashtest
```

I've also tried using AlarmManager, in this variant:

```
public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent (getBaseContext (), RestartActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  PendingIntent pending =
    PendingIntent.getActivity (getBaseContext (), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

  AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarm.set (AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis () + 3000, pending);

  System.exit (1);
}
```

In this case, RestartActivity doesn't display at all, and I see a line in the logcat like this:

```
05-29 22:06:46.841 1465-11842/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.perinote.crashtest appid=10170 user=0: from pid 12551
```

What is causing Android to so badly want to kill the process that just started?

Comment: Have you tried using **android.os.Process.killProcess**?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's been a while. This isn't currently on my priority list so it will be a "while" longer before I try anything else. Thanks.

Comment: Do not use **System.exit (1)**, as it doesn't clean up the task stack and doesn't give the OS a chance to cleanly exit your app.  Read more about task stack here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavily edited as I mistook what you were trying to do.

The first version doesn't work because you're sending a pending intent to your own application.  Just because its a pending intent doesn't mean it will be run in a new process, it means that whatever other app calls it (such as the launcher for notifications) it will be activated as if your own process launched the intent.  So it can access private activities, for example.  Its actually started in your process before you're killed, then it gets killed with you.

The, the alarm manager doesn't work at all because the pending intent in it must be to a BroadcastReceiver-  it doesn't accept one to a Service or Activity.  If you put a receiver in your manifest and use a pending intent to that, you can probably get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe. So, to be clear, you aren't aware of any other methods of restarting an app? Assuming not, I'll try implementing a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Not offhand.  Its not something I've ever tried to do.

Comment: Seems to be working - have only tested on one device so far. Question: apparently, for security reasons, my receiver will be ignored until I have manually started the app. That is, the AlarmManager will trigger the broadcast but Android will not start my receiver unless I have already run the app at least once. Each time I try to run my code from the debugger, my receiver never starts. I have to run it by selecting it from Applications on my device. Is there a way to get it to work from the debugger?

Comment: The receiver isn't firing at all on my 5.1 device. Any thoughts?

Comment: @PeriHartman How did you register your receiver - in AndroidManifest or in Java?

Comment: I changed to another mechanism and I don't think I have the BroadcastReceiver experimental code any more. Some day I'll have a deeper look and maybe try this again...